# How to retain the session with paramiko

Tags: linux, shell, session, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to do something like this:
I have a ssh session connected via paramiko. Now I want to issue commands that depends on the previous commands.

For eg; I first issue a 'cd ~/my_folder' and then a 'ls', since the ssh sessions are seperate for each of the command, my first command will not affect the second command.

How do I maintain sessions across multiple commands? I use the ssh.exec_command() function to issue the commands.

I know I can do something like, ssh.exec_command('cd ~/my_folder; ls') but, let's just assume that I cannot do that in my environment.

Comment: Post your code. What have you tried? With paramiko, you open and then close an ssh session, seems you could pass multiple shell commands before closing the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SSHClient.invoke_shell` to start an interactive shell. You can set the prompt to some easily recognized value then send commands and scan through received data looking for the prompt to demarcate the returned data.

Another option is to use `pexpect`'s `pxssh` module which has done some of the heavy lifting for you.